# setState({}) is not changing my boolean value In react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I am trying to show/hide my input field in react Native firstly i set my `showFilters` true in state and in my function i have set it to false... like this...

```
hide(){
        console.log("hello");
        this.setState({showFilters: false}); 
      }
```

here is my `this.state` ...

```
constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {
            showFilters:true,
            radioButtons: [
            {
              label: 'Freelancer',
              value: 'freelancer',
              checked: true,
              color: '#323232',
              disabled: false,
              onPress: this.hide(),
              size: 11

            },

        {
          label: 'Jobs',
          value: 'jobs',
          checked: false,
          color: '#323232',
          disabled: false,
          size: 11

        },
        {
          label: 'Employer',
          value: 'employer',
          checked: false,
          color: '#323232',
          disabled: false,           
          size: 11   
        } ]
```

I want to hide my layout when press radio button...

```
{ this.state.showFilters   ?
                <TextInput style={{fontSize:17 , height:45}}  editable = {true} placeholder="Hello"></TextInput> : null
            }
```

the terminal is showing hello message but not changing the state..
showing warning...

```
Warning: Can't call %s on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};`
```

here is Radio button code

```
render(){
        let selectedItem = this.state.radioButtons.find(e => e.checked == true);
        selectedItem = selectedItem ? selectedItem.value : this.state.radioButtons[0].value;
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header style ={{shadowRadius: 0,shadowOffset: {height: 0,},}}
            backgroundColor="#ff5851"
            androidStatusBarColor="#ff5851"
            leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff' }}
            centerComponent={{ text: 'Start Your Search', style: { color: '#fff',fontWeight:'500', fontSize:20 , width:'100%',fontSize:20, paddingTop:9 ,display:'flex', flexDirection:'column', alignItems:'center'  , justifyContent:'center' , height:40 , borderRadius:20 , alignSelf:'center' , textAlign:'center'  } }}
              />
            <ScrollView>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: '600' , marginBottom:10 , color:'#323232' ,fontWeight:'500', fontSize:20 , marginLeft:10 , marginTop:10 , marginBottom:15 , marginTop:15 }}>Narrow Your Search</Text>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'column' , backgroundColor:'#fff' , paddingLeft:10}}>
            <View style={{borderBottomColor: '#dddddd', borderBottomWidth: 0.6 , marginLeft:-10  , marginBottom:10}}/>
            <Text style={{ marginBottom:10 }}>Narrow Your Search</Text>
            <RadioGroup style={{marginBottom:10 , flexDirection:'row'}}
            color='#ff5851'
            labelStyle={{ fontSize: 14, }}
            radioButtons={this.state.radioButtons}
            onPress={radioButtons => this.setState({ radioButtons })}
            style={{ paddingTop: 20 }}
            />
```

Comment: Please show radiobutton code.

Comment: @firats I have edited my code

Comment: try with this.showFilters  out side of 
constuctor(){
super()
this.statte = {}
this.showFilters = false 
}

Comment: Please Explain @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i am not getting your point

Comment: Not allowing me to use it outside the state @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Answer (score 1):

First get rid of `onPress: this.hide()` in your constructor. Like this:

```
super();
        this.state = {
          showFilters:true,
          data: [
          {
            label: 'Freelancer',
            value: 'freelancer',
            checked: true,
            color: '#323232',
            disabled: false,
            size: 11

          },

          {
            label: 'Jobs',
            value: 'jobs',
            checked: false,
            color: '#323232',
            disabled: false,
            size: 11

          },
          {
            label: 'Employer',
            value: 'employer',
            checked: false,
            color: '#323232',
            disabled: false,           
            size: 11   
          } ],
        };
```

Then write onPress Function instead of hide function

```
onPress = data => {
  let selectedButton = data.find(e => e.selected == true);
  selectedButton = selectedButton ? selectedButton.value : 
     this.state.data[0].label;

  if (selectedButton === 'freelancer') {
    this.setState({ data, showFilters: false });
  } else {
    this.setState({ data, showFilters: true });
  }
}
```

Last in your render function try this:

```
<RadioGroup style={{marginBottom:10 , flexDirection:'row'}}
        color='#ff5851'
        labelStyle={{ fontSize: 14, }}
        radioButtons={this.state.data}
        onPress={this.onPress}
        style={{ paddingTop: 20 }}
/>
```

Code is working on my machine. When you tap freelancer radiobutton showfilter changes to false value.

Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Change `onPress: this.hide(),` to `onPress: this.hide`.You write `onPress: this.hide()` so you call this.hide() in constructor.

Comment: Hi try once by passing props in 

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

Answer (score 0):

S.Hasjmi

```
constructor() {

        super();

        this.state = {
            radioButtons: [
            {
              label: 'Freelancer',
              value: 'freelancer',
              checked: true,
              color: '#323232',
              disabled: false,
              onPress: this.hide(),
              size: 11

            },
            // your code ......
           ]
         }
    this.showFilters = true
   }

hide(){
        this.showFilters =  false
      }
```

and layout like

```
{ this.showFilters   ?
                <TextInput style={{fontSize:17 , height:45}}  editable = {true} placeholder="Hello"></TextInput> : null
            }
```

try with this.showFilters

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call `setState` with a callback and pass the previous state:

```
setState(prevState => {
   showfilter: !prevState.showFilters
})
```